# Two Closest Numbers to a number X

Tags: programming

I have a dataframe with a list of numbers in column A in Python, and I would like to get the two closest numbers in this list to a specific number X. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force way of doing this is to create a new Series that is `abs(A-X)`. You sort the new series and select the indices of the top two items, which can be used to reference the two rows in the original data frame.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!!